# "Constructor" pronunciation debate

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, vowels

I have a debate with my friend on the pronunciation of “constructor” word that he claims there cannot be a pronunciation which is of IPA phonetic as following unlike mine that

**/ˈkɑn.stɹʌktəɹ/**

of which **ˈkɑn** part is the ongoing debate. He says I have never heard such a pronunciation. That part must be either **kɒn** or **kən** yet not **kɑn**. We are not native speakers.

Further, I claim that there can be such usage since I see from [the link](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/construct) on which contruct’s noun form is spelled as **kɑn**.

Could you provide your ideas, if possible, along with a video/conference link which is in favor of mine (no pun intended)?

Comment: Google: **How to pronounce constructor**. There are several helpful sites

Comment: I don't understand IPA vowels, but the first syllable will either have the schwa vowel, or it will be the same as "con" meaning a fraud or deceit.

Comment: Asking about pronunciation of one word is off-topic as it can be looked up in a dictionary

Answer (score 3):

The noun *construct* is pronounced /ˈk**ɒ**n.strʌkt/ in British English and /ˈk**ɑ**n.strʌkt/ in American English, but the verb *construct* is pronounced /kənˈstrʌkt/ in both. The agent noun *constructor* is derived not from the noun but from the verb *construct* (the suffix *-or* is chiefly attachable to verb bases) so it's pronounced /**kən**ˈstrʌktə(r)/. I've never heard /kɒnstrʌktə(r)/ or /kɑnstrʌktə(r)/.